# Are convergent sequences closed under uniform convergence?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, double-sequence

Setting: Let $Y$ be a metric space and let $a_{n,k}\in Y$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose $a_{n,k}\to a_{\bullet, k}$ uniforly  as $n\to\infty$. Suppose the sequences $\{a_{n,k}\}\to A_n$ as $k\to \infty$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, .

---

There are two questions in my mind:

1. Is it possible that $a_{\bullet,k}$ diverge as $k\to\infty$?
2. Is it possible that $A_n$ diverges while $a_{\bullet,k}$ converge?

I appreciate help in all forms.

---

The motivation for me to ask these questions is that I know the following three properties

- boundedness
- unboundedness
- continuous

are closed under uniform convergent. That is, the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of bounded function must be bounded, and vice versa for the other two properties, but I cannot prove nor disprove that convergence of sequences in metric space is also closed under uniform convergent.

Also, I have already proved the following Theorem by myself, and I was trying to figure out if the hypotheses are all necessary. I figured that if the hypothesis ($A_n\to A$) in the following Theorem is implied by the other two, then the statement convergent sequences in metric space are closed under uniform convergent is true. Thanks for any help.

[image]

---

Comment: I do not understand how "if anyone can solve the second question I gave above, the first question is then also solved". I think the answer to the 2nd question is no, but this does not help to answer "yes if $Y$ is not complete" to the first one.

Comment: @AnneBauval You are correct. I will fix that part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The answer to the second question is no. If $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{\bullet,k}=A$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ exists and equals $A$.
  Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $N$ be such that $\forall n\ge N,\forall k,d(a_{n,k},a_{\bullet,k})<\epsilon/2$, and $K$ be such that $\forall k\ge K,d(a_{\bullet,k},A)<\epsilon/2$. Then,
  $$\forall n\ge N,\forall k\ge K,d(a_{n,k},A)<\epsilon$$
  hence
  $$\forall n\ge N,d(A_n,A)\le\epsilon.$$
- The answer to the first question is yes. Take for instance
  $$Y=\Bbb R^*,\quad a_{n,k}=\frac1n+\frac1k.$$
- However, if $Y$ is complete, the answer to the first question is no (i.e. the answer to the question in the title is yes), because if $(a_{n,k})_k$ converges uniformly as $n\to\infty$ then it is uniformly Cauchy, hence $(A_n)_n$ is Cauchy.